# cookie does not get stored when I add domain as a path

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am setting my cookie as follows:

```
document.cookie =`${name}=${value};expires=${expires.toUTCString()};path=/`;
```

and it works.

However recently I got a request that other corss subdomain access to the cookie is not allowed and that is why I am adding the domain as a path and when I set it as follows:

```
document.cookie =`${name}=${value};expires=${expires.toUTCString()};path=/`+ServiceUrls.prototype.getDomainUrl();
```

I cannot see it saved as a cookie.
Is there anything wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain#answer-23086139

Comment: @KyleMiller Hi Kyle. that is part of the issue but not all. I am not sure why I can not see the cookie saved at all. So in the first place when I add path rather than / the cookie wont get saved

Comment: You need to have it set as a Header option in the request vs setting it in JS

Comment: Later on in the question this looks to have a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain#answer-46434609